# Opening or dismissing rich push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I'm currently working with Content Extensions and have my own custom UI. Within this view I have a button where users can interact with the view.

The only thing I can't seem to find is a way to dismiss the notification or open the app, when the button is tapped since currently the notification just stays open, because I've added the following key into the content extensions Info.plist `UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled`.

Just to show an example of this below is my action within the notification extension.

```
- (IBAction)testCustomDismissDidTouch:(id)sender {
  // How would I control the notification from here? I.e. Open the app or Dismiss the notification.
}
```

Comment: try UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOptionDismiss and UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOptionDismissAndForwardAction for dismissing and opening app.

Comment: @manishsharma93 This can only be used within the protocol function didReceiveNotificationResponse, I don't know how I could call this within my IBAction, if you could provide an example I'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: @Tunds did you find a way to do this?